# Changing the action of a default ios application

Tags: iphone, ios

I was wondering if it would be possible to change, or at least interfere, with how one of the Apple applications works. For example, would it be possible to have my app run in the background and have an alert box pop up instead of sending an email in the Mail app. The action could have a 'cancel' or 'send' option. I was just wondering if Apple would allow this if it was clearly stated as an app that would interfere with the current function of another app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is it possible to do this, nor would Apple allow it.